# Send email after Paypal Express Checkout order completes

Tags: php, api, email, paypal, express-checkout

I'm trying to subscribe a client to an AWeber mailing list upon ordering a product on a website. I've completed the ordering process, and I also have my server sending an email to AWeber to enlist the client.

For some reason the emails bounce when sent from my server (due to a DNS error) and the ISP doesn't know how to fix it.

Thus, I am looking for an external mailing solution on PayPal itself. Is there any way to have PayPal send an email upon order completion (sort of like what it can do with Buy Now buttons)?

If so, how can I instruct it to send the email, and set the contents/destination?

Comment: paypal sends a token back when the payment is complete, you should check their documentation

Comment: I'm aware of the checkout process. I am completing the orders fine. What I'm asking is if there's a way to send an email *from PayPal's server* after I execute the DoExpressCheckoutPayment method.

Comment: Why does the email have to come from PayPal's server?  
When the order completes, send the email from your own server.

Comment: @Ed: Did you even read the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a script which will be triggered via PayPal IPN and when triggered, subscribes the email address through Aweber API (https://labs.aweber.com/)? Use their API instead of sending an email to subscribe an email address.

Comment: OH! I was having a look through their API, and it seemed as though it was read-only. However, upon closer inspection you're right -- I **can** add subscribers through it. That's much better than doing it through email, anyway! Thanks :)

Comment: Nope; after another look through the API docs, I learned that the API **can** perform *some* write functionality (such as moving subscribers b/t lists) but it cannot create subscribers. It says this in the 3rd section of this FAQ page: https://labs.aweber.com/docs/faq

Comment: Hmmm, if API is not the solution, you can make a post request to the subscription form action url with required fields.